# Android app keeps crashing, trying to implement an onclick listener

Tags: android

I am trying to implement an `onClick` listener, but the app crashes when trying to load `show_products.xml`.

In **show_products.xml**, I accidently had `tools:context=".LoginActivity"`, but the app did not crash when it was like this. But after attempting to change it to `tools:context=".ShowProducts"`. The app does not go to this view and now the app crashes. I tried putting breakpoints on `LoginActivity.kt` and `ShowProducts.kt`, but it does call the `onCreate` method on either one.

**show_products.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    tools:context=".ShowProducts"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/get_products"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="30dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="20dp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="Get Products"
        android:onClick="getProducts"
        />

    ...


</LinearLayout>
```

**ShowProducts.kt**

```
class ShowProducts : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val TAG = "ShowProducts"
    lateinit var myApi: IMyAPI

    val btn_get_products = findViewById<Button>(R.id.get_products) //this is not being used

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.show_products)

        myApi = RetrofitClient.getInstance().create(IMyAPI::class.java)
    }

    fun getProducts(view: View) {
        val call = myApi.findAll()
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Product>> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Product>>, response: Response<List<Product>>) {
                Log.e(TAG, "getProducts onResponse: " + response.body())
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Product>>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e(TAG, "getProducts onFailure: " + t.localizedMessage)
            }
        })

    }

    ...


}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kumoapp2">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".UpdateInfoActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen" />
        <activity android:name=".ShowProducts"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SignUpActivity" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**LoginActivity.kt**

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var iMyAPI: IMyAPI
    var compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        back_to_register_textview.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this, SignUpActivity::class.java))
            finish()
        }

        login_button.setOnClickListener {
            doLogin()
        }


    }

    private fun doLogin() {
        ...


        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email_edittext_login.text.toString(),
            password_edittext_login.text.toString()
        )
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val user = auth.currentUser
                    updateUI(user)
                } else {
                    //If failed
                    updateUI(null)
                }
            }
    }

    public override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        //Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly
        val currentUser = auth.currentUser
        updateUI(currentUser)
    }

    private fun updateUI(currentUser: FirebaseUser?) {
        if (currentUser != null) {
            Log.d("LoginActivity User:", currentUser.displayName + " : " + currentUser.uid + " : " + currentUser.email );
            startActivity(Intent(this, ShowProducts::class.java))
            finish()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Login failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
2020-03-29 11:41:12.613 17437-17437/com.example.kumoapp2 D/LoginActivity User::  : IPhZuUhY6waux0JH8CMc6Nyog5u2 : alextest@test.com
2020-03-29 11:41:12.647 17437-17543/com.example.kumoapp2 I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
2020-03-29 11:41:12.659 17437-17437/com.example.kumoapp2 W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@82a5d1e
2020-03-29 11:41:12.679 17437-17437/com.example.kumoapp2 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-03-29 11:41:12.695 17437-17437/com.example.kumoapp2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.kumoapp2, PID: 17437
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kumoapp2/com.example.kumoapp2.ShowProducts}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2843)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:159)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:157)
        at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:675)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:692)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:214)
        at com.example.kumoapp2.ShowProducts.<init>(ShowProducts.kt:24)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:41)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2831)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
2020-03-29 11:41:12.879 17437-17454/com.example.kumoapp2 I/xample.kumoapp: Background concurrent copying GC freed 17059(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 9(176KB) LOS objects, 50% free, 1967KB/3MB, paused 7.446ms total 200.489ms
2020-03-29 11:41:13.446 17437-17527/com.example.kumoapp2 W/xample.kumoapp: Verification of void com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzma.<init>() took 128.352ms
2020-03-29 11:41:13.707 17437-17527/com.example.kumoapp2 I/FA: App measurement initialized, version: 21028
2020-03-29 11:41:13.708 17437-17527/com.example.kumoapp2 I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2020-03-29 11:41:13.708 17437-17527/com.example.kumoapp2 I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.kumoapp2
2020-03-29 11:41:13.708 17437-17527/com.example.kumoapp2 D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
```

Comment: please provide us with crash stacktrace

Comment: Hold on, I will post, I was wondering why I did not get enough info at first, but now I see info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In showProducts.kt ,

`val btn_get_products = findViewById<Button>(R.id.get_products)`

you must put this line below of

`setContentView(R.layout.show_products)`

Tip : you can't assign any element before setContentView method

Comment: I am not using `btn_get_products`. I already have `setContentView(R.layout.show_products)` in `onCreate` method.

Comment: actually, I just learned something new, I removed this `val btn_get_products = findViewById<Button>(R.id.get_products)` and now it is not crashing, I did not know it would crash, even though I am not using it.

Answer (score -1):

Open the Google Play Store app.
Tap the three stacked lines “hamburger” icon.
Tap “My apps & games.”
Scroll down and tap “Android System WebView” from the apps list.
In the app’s settings page, tap “Uninstall” to disable it.
Follow these steps to avoid crashing of apps 
That happens even due to weak internet connection, 
Hope this was helpful